# Bash Expect not response to keystroke when using spawn -open

Tags: linux, expect

I have an expect bash to enter BIOS setup when machine bootup via serial redirection of that target machine. The following is my script where i use `spawn` to read & write the serial port, but the keystroke (Del) used to enter BIOS is not respond in that script

```
set timeout -1
match_max 100000
set port /dev/ttyUSB0
set rate 115200

exec stty -F $port $rate
spawn -open [open $port w+]

expect "American Megatrends"
sleep 1
send -- "^\[\[3~"
send_user "\nok\n"
```

The last line "ok" is printed that's means my keyword is expected but it doesn't go into BIOS setting

Meanwhile in another script where it read and write with `screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200` able to send the keystroke and enter BIOS setup successfully.

Anyone could help on this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`^[` means `CTRL-[` which is the ESC char (0x1b or 033) so you can try like this:

```
send -- "\033\[3~"
```